# Вывод уведомления о новой версии с блокировкой прошлых версий приложения

Tags: android, уведомления, обновления

Как в приложении андроид реализовать функцию блокировки входа в старую версию приложение если есть обновление?
Я написал уже около 20 версий приложение в некоторых были ошибки. Но у меня есть пользователи в которых ещё начальная версия приложения где-то 5 -10 и тд. в Консоле постоянно выпадают ошибки что они попадают на одни и те же грабли. Много раз писал что в уведомления что выходит обновление и тд. но им без разницы. 
Понимаю что с ними ничего не сделаю.
Как сделать так что бы хотябы с 21 версии приложения если есть приложение в плей маркете выше версии не можно было войти в приложение пред этим не обновив его?

Comment: [Получить текущую версию приложения из игрового магазина](https://mobikul.com/get-current-version-application-playstore/)  вторая ссылка    [Always get Latest Version 0.0.0.0 update from GOOGLE_PLAY](https://github.com/javiersantos/AppUpdater/issues/132)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Видео](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DJeT2vm9IO8) 
[Исходный код](https://www.programmingdesire.com/2018/12/auto-check-for-update-function-for.html)
Имплементация

```
   implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.10.2'
```

Исходник:

```
    import android.app.Activity;  
     import android.app.ProgressDialog;  
     import android.content.DialogInterface;  
     import android.content.Intent;  
     import android.content.pm.PackageInfo;  
     import android.content.pm.PackageManager;  
     import android.net.Uri;  
     import android.os.AsyncTask;  
     import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;  
     import android.widget.Toast;  
     import org.jsoup.Jsoup;  
     public class AppUpdateChecker {  
       private Activity activity;  
       public AppUpdateChecker(Activity activity) {  
         this.activity = activity;  
       }  
       //current version of app installed in the device  
       private String getCurrentVersion(){  
         PackageManager pm = activity.getPackageManager();  
         PackageInfo pInfo = null;  
         try {  
           pInfo = pm.getPackageInfo(activity.getPackageName(),0);  
         } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e1) {  
           e1.printStackTrace();  
         }  
         return pInfo.versionName;  
       }  
       private class GetLatestVersion extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {  
         private String latestVersion;  
         private ProgressDialog progressDialog;  
         private boolean manualCheck;  
         GetLatestVersion(boolean manualCheck) {  
           this.manualCheck = manualCheck;  
         }  
         @Override  
         protected void onPostExecute(String s) {  
           super.onPostExecute(s);  
           if (manualCheck)  
           {  
             if (progressDialog!=null)  
             {  
               if (progressDialog.isShowing())  
               {  
                 progressDialog.dismiss();  
               }  
             }  
           }  
           String currentVersion = getCurrentVersion();  
           //If the versions are not the same  
           if(!currentVersion.equals(latestVersion)&&latestVersion!=null){  
             final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);  
             builder.setTitle("An Update is Available");  
             builder.setMessage("Its better to update now");  
             builder.setPositiveButton("Update", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {  
               @Override  
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {  
                 //Click button action  
                 activity.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id="+activity.getPackageName())));  
                 dialog.dismiss();  
               }  
             });  
             builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {  
               @Override  
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {  
                 //Cancel button action  
               }  
             });  
             builder.setCancelable(false);  
             builder.show();  
           }else {  
             if (manualCheck) {  
               Toast.makeText(activity, "No Update Available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
             }  
           }  
         }  
         @Override  
         protected void onPreExecute() {  
           super.onPreExecute();  
           if (manualCheck) {  
             progressDialog=new ProgressDialog(activity);  
             progressDialog.setMessage("Checking For Update.....");  
             progressDialog.setCancelable(false);  
             progressDialog.show();  
           }  
         }  
         @Override  
         protected String doInBackground(String... params) {  
           try {  
             //It retrieves the latest version by scraping the content of current version from play store at runtime  
             latestVersion = Jsoup.connect("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + activity.getPackageName() + "&hl=it")  
                 .timeout(30000)  
                 .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; WindowsNT 5.1; en-US; rv1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6")  
                 .referrer("http://www.google.com")  
                 .get()  
                 .select(".hAyfc .htlgb")  
                 .get(7)  
                 .ownText();  
             return latestVersion;  
           } catch (Exception e) {  
             return latestVersion;  
           }  
         }  
       }  
       public void checkForUpdate(boolean manualCheck)  
       {  
         new GetLatestVersion(manualCheck).execute();  
       }  
     }
```

Позначка проверки в Активити

```
 AppUpdateChecker appUpdateChecker=new AppUpdateChecker(this);  //pass the activity in constructure
 appUpdateChecker.checkForUpdate(false); //mannual check false here
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно сделать процесс который будет запускаться при каждом запуске приложения, и будет проверять в маркете наличие новой версии приложения. Если ее нет, то все хорошо и пользователь будет пользоваться приложением как-всегда. Но вот если все-таки новая версия есть и она доступна для скачивания, то я бы сначала советовал уведомлять пользователя о том что новая версия есть и было бы неплохо обновится. Если пользователь проигнорировал ваше уведомление, то дальше можно его уведомлять о том что в случае откладывания обновления следующий запуск приложения будет невозможен пока пользователь не обновится.

Дальше по поводу запуска и проверки. Я могу вам предложить такой вариант: ввести в вашем приложении бул переменную которая будет отвечать за то что ваше приложение последней версии и его обновлять не нужно. Эту переменную вы можете хранить на устройстве и дальше ее при запуске проверять. Эта переменная изначально будет равна true и ее (переменную) может изменить только ваша проверка на наличие новой версии. Если новой версии нету то переменная остается true, а если все-таки новая версия есть - false. А дальше вы при запуске активити проверяете эту переменную как-то так:

```
if(updated)
{
//приложение свежее и пусть пользователь не волнуется
}
else
{
//приложение устарело и его нужно обновить
}
```

если приложение старое и проверка это доказала то вы можете вывести алерт с предложением либо выйти либо перейти на страницу с приложением для обновления. И так делать постоянно пока не сработает проверка и не покажет что приложение свежее.

вот есть [одна](http://revisitingandroid.blogspot.com/2016/12/programmatically-check-play-store-for.html) и [вторая](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25201349/programmatically-check-play-store-for-app-updates) ссылка по вашему вопросу.

Возможно у меня неправильное виденье вашей проблемы и я предложил неверное решение. Надеюсь хоть чем-то помог, если что-то будет непонятно - не стесняйтесь и спрашивайте, помогу чем смогу. Удачи :)

Comment: Может вы посоветуете какое-то видео как это реализовать более подробно ?

Comment: тут видео не поможет)) я лично таких видеороликов не видел, у вас есть проверка для получения последней версии приложения с маркета?

Comment: У меня нет проверки последний версии приложения. Я даже не знаю как её реализовать

Comment: @VladBulan, обновил вопрос - там есть две ссылки которые попались мне на глаза)

Answer (score 1):

Знаю что ответ уже приняли, но я чуть чуть дополню его.  У Firebase есть отличная фича

https://firebase.google.com/products/remote-config/

Вы в него можете добавить номер, например, последней актуальной версии и в приложении блокировать все, что меньше этого значения

Comment: К сожалению таким способом вы привяжете себя к сервису в котором не нуждаетесь, намного проще сделать проверку тем же самым Jsoup нежели использовать Firebase. при условии что автор не использует Firebase в своем проекте для иных целей