# Установка приложений без участия пользователя android

Tags: java, android

Как программно установить/обновить приложение?

**Android 4.4.2**

**Программа которая будет устанавливать приложения будет системным(system/app) и будет подписан ключом системы.**

Пробовал такой вариант https://github.com/paulononaka/Android-InstallInBackgroundSample не работает. Выдает ошибку

> RuntimeException("Stub!")

при инициализации packageManager

Comment: Попробуйте метод `installNewApk()` отсюда: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/543222/17609

Comment: Вот мне уже отвечали на подобный вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/902034/%D0%91%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%BB%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F

Comment: @DuosDuo, в теории это может сработать без рута в ваших условиях. Но надо, конечно, пробовать)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В итоге написал следующий код:

```
fun install(filePath: String) {
        var inputStream: InputStream? = null
        try { 
            val sb = StringBuilder()
            sb.append("pm install -r ")
            sb.append(filePath)
            val proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(sb.toString())
            inputStream = proc.inputStream
            val bufferedReader = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(inputStream))
            var line: String
            val log = StringBuilder()
            while (bufferedReader.readLine().also { line = it } != null) {
                log.append(line + "\n")
            }
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        } finally {
            if (inputStream != null) {
                try {
                    inputStream.close()
                } catch (e: IOException) {
                    e.printStackTrace()
                }
            }
        }
    }
```